Rsync Service on WSL Ubuntu stops running after restart fo Windows Server 2019
I am running Ubuntu 20.04 WSL on a Windows Server 2019. As it's Server 2019, so i could not set up WSL 2 and could not use systemd. I am using init.d and the rsync template inside it. I have set up rsync service using the template and upon starting the service manually using sudo service rsync start , i was able to transfer the files from my directory to my destination server. My problem is that as soon as i restart the machine on which i have Windows Server 2019 installed and the Ubuntu running , the rsync daemon and the rsync service stops. How can i keep it running even if the system restarts? Is there a way to do it in configs or via setting up a batch file?
